The pixel value using inspector and sampleRegions are different at same scale
I want to get pixel value from qualityMosaic image with a point feature. But I found that the pixel value from sampleRegions and from Inspector are different. However, if I extract pixel value from the first NDVI image, the pixel value from sampleRegions and from Inspector are same. When I use Inspector, I keep the map scale at 1m/px.
Why this will happen? And which result is correct? inspector or sampleRegions?
var test_point = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.85540986637345, 37.32286843014314]);


// Import the Landsat 8 TOA image collection.
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA');
var ImageCol = l8.filterBounds(test_point)
              .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = ImageCol.map(addNDVI);
var firstNDVI = withNDVI.first().select('NDVI');

// get first NDVI image
var firstNDVI_sample = firstNDVI.sampleRegions({
  collection: test_point,
  scale:30
})
print("firstNDVI_sample:",firstNDVI_sample)
Map.addLayer(firstNDVI,{},"first image of NDVI ")


// Make a "greenest" pixel composite.
var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI').select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2','NDVI']);

// after qualityMosaic, the image projection has change, so set to Landsat image crs
var greenest_sample = greenest.sampleRegions({
  collection: test_point,
  projection: 'EPSG:32610', 
  scale:30
})
print("greenest_sample:",greenest_sample)
var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(greenest, visParams, 'Greenest pixel composite');

Map.addLayer(test_point,{color: 'cyan'},"test_point")


It's a projection thing. The map in the Code Editor is EPSG:3857 but you use EPSG:32610 when sampling the pixel. If you use EPSG:3857 when sampling, the values match.
